# How can i authorize a route in react with redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router

Here I want that only loggedin user should be able to open the profile route. What is the best way to do it?

main.js

```
let store = createStore(todoApp, applyMiddleware(thunkMiddleware));

render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <Router  history={browserHistory}>
            <div className="container">
                <Route exact path="/" component={Login}/>
                    <Route path="/profile" component={Profile} />
            </div>
        </Router>
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('root')
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do somthing like :

```
<Route path="/profile" component={RequiresAuth(Profile)} />
```

And create a authentication function like :

```
function RequiresAuth(ComposedComponent) {
    class Authenticate extends Component {

        render() {
            if (!userAuthenticated) {      // Check if user is authenticated
                return null;
            } else {
                return (
                    <ComposedComponent {...this.props} />
                );
            }
        }
    }
}
```